# Selecting rows from numpy ndarray when groups are known

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array `x` and a list of tags `cls` which preserves the order of `x`, and records the class each element from `x` belongs to. For example, for two different classes `0` and `1`:

```
x = [47 21 16 19 38]
cls = [0 0 1 0 1]
```

meaning that `47, 21, 19` belong together, and so do `16, 38`.

Is there a pythonic way to select elements from `x` by class?

Now I'm doing

```py
for clusterId in np.unique(cls):
indices = [i for i in range(len(cls)) if cls[i]==clusterId]
print 'Class ', clusterId
for idx in indices:
    print '\t', x[idx,].tolist()
```

but I can't believe there is nothing more elegant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cls` is perfect for constructing a boolean index array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([47, 21, 16, 19, 38])
>>> cls = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1],dtype=bool)
>>> x[cls]
array([16, 38])
>>> x[~cls]
array([47, 21, 19])
```

Note that if `cls` isn't a boolean array already, you can make it one using `ndarray.astype`:

```
>>> cls = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
>>> x[cls]  #Not what you want
array([47, 47, 21, 47, 21])
>>> x[cls.astype(bool)]  #what you want.
array([16, 38])
```

In the general case where you have a `cls` array and you want to pick out only elements with that index:

```
>>> x[cls == 0]
array([47, 21, 19])
>>> x[cls == 1]
array([16, 38])
```

To find all the classes that you have, you can use `np.unique(cls)`

Comment: OP seems to have given two classes 0,1 as an example only and is searching for a more general solution (just like his solution does).

Comment: @eumiro -- Ahh... I see.  So OP is looking for `x[cls==0]` or `x[cls==1]`.